# Make Kingswaysoft truncate input data that is too long

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I have an SSIS project that I'm using to automate pulling CRM data into a SQL Server Database using Kingswaysoft. These SSIS packages are autogenerated, so my solution to this issue needs to be compatible with that.

The description field on Contact in CRM is a nvarchar(2000), but this CRM org still has old data, and some of those old contact records have a description longer than 2000 characters. When I try to pull those using Kingsway, I get this error:

> Error: 0xC002F304 at Stage Data for contact, Export contact Data [2]: An error occurred with the following error message: "The input value for 'description' field (or one of its related fields) does not fit into the output buffer, please consider increasing the output column's Length property or changing its data type to one that can accommodate more data such as ntext (DT_NTEXT). This change can be done using the component's Advanced Editor window.".

This makes sense, since I'm pulling a column longer than specified in the metadata, but the problem is that I want to ignore this error, truncate the column, and continue the data load. Obviously I could set the column to DT_NTEXT and not worry about it, but since these packages are autogenerated I have no way of knowing beforehand which columns have old data and which don't, so I won't know which should be DT_NTEXT.

So is there a way to make Kingswaysoft truncate input data which is longer than what's specified in the metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft as your integration solution. For this situation, unfortunately there is no way to make that work without making those changes in the component’s Advanced Editor.

If the source component just simply ignores the error and truncates the value, you will lose some of your data and thus affect the data integrity during the integration. Therefore, you may need to change the data type to DT_NTEXT or increase the length of this field in order to handle this situation properly. Alternatively, you can try to change the field length on your CRM side so that the SSIS package can be generated correctly.